# Commonly used OID for Linux Servers

Tags: virtual-machines, openldap

I want to extend the schema for my ApacheDS (OpenLDAP) server to track Virtual Machine info (Operating System, Memory, Disk Space, Processor Peak, etc.) but I don't know what OID to use, if there even is one.

What do y'all use for Computer/Server Objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to register your own OID, you can borrow a piece of Microsoft's OID namespace by reading [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677620%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and following the instructions.  You will need access to a Windows machine to generate the code.

Comment: That looks like the best option at the moment.  I've exported an LDIF so I can modify and do an import after I get all of the related attrs lined up.  More than likely will need to add new ones to take into account linux-specific stuff.

Answer (score 5):

The commonly used OID for any extension you want to make is `1.3.6.1.4.1.PEN.whatever-you-want` - where PEN is your IANA-assigned [Private Enterprise Number](http://pen.iana.org/pen/PenApplication.page).
If no company has done what you want yet you should build an appropriate OID tree under `1.3.6.1.4.1.PEN.` to handle it.

Private Enterprise Numbers are free, and you can define the OID tree under them for whatever needs you have.
Do your company a favor and document said structure thoroughly (particularly as you add new stuff to the tree) - this will also come in handy later if you want to release a MIB file and your software to the rest of the world.

Comment: I appreciate the promptness of your reply!  I am hoping that someone has done the latter, as I have no fear of doing the former - but I wanted to know if someone has already established a good standard to use thus far.  I try not to reinvent the wheel as best I can.